# Loading PNGs with BitmapFactory.decodeFile is randomly very slow

Tags: java, android

In my app, I use BitmapFactory.decodeFile to load .png files that are the size of the screen. Sometimes the .png files will load in roughly 0.5 seconds. Occasionally, they will take about 10  or 15 seconds to load on a Droid phone which is a horrifically long time to ask the user to wait. As the user can pick any from a set of pictures in a gallery to load, I cannot practically load these images in advance.

I understand that SD card performance is unpredictable, but I'm really confused how they can be this unpredictable. I've been playing with the built-in stock Android gallery and haven't noticed this kind of loading behaviour for the same .png files.

Can anyone give me any advice on how to improve the speed at which these files are loaded? I can't see many options myself.

Answer (score 0):

While making avd just try to give size of SD card and if given then increase it.......